# webpack CLI error - [webpack-cli] Error: Unknown option '--inline'

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

When I try to start my Preact app using **npm start** it gives this error

```
[webpack-cli] Error: Unknown option '--inline'
```

This is my package.json script

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --inline --hot --progress --content-base public --port 3333"
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's been deprecated, and is true by default now.

> You can't use inline option (it will be always true in next major).

From [this comment on a related issue](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1829#issuecomment-499470813).
I couldn't find anything more *authoritative* about the change